# Fetch local file data in R/Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyapps, shinyjs

Following an idea from from https://github.com/jpowell96/readFilesWithFetch/blob/master/index.html, I'm trying to read data from a .csv file from the 'www' folder but I get only the 'Reading file' line and the data is not shown. I tried with full path too in fetch *(fetch(file:///C:/.../www/this_data.csv'))* but got the same results.

Any idea to make it work? (Currently working in Windows but eventually will port it to shinyapps.io.)

Many thanks

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyjs)
  ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),

      tags$div(
       tags$html("Reading file"),

       tags$script("
         fetch('./www/this_data.csv')
          .then(response => response.text()) 
          .then(csvString => {
         // Split the csv into rows
         const rows = csvString.split('\n');
         for (row of rows) {
           // Split the row into each of the comma separated values
           console.log(row.split(','));
         }
       });
       ")
    )
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {}
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is **this_data.csv**:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close
1/2/2007,50.03978,50.11778,49.95041,50.11778
1/3/2007,50.2305,50.42188,50.2305,50.39767
1/4/2007,50.42096,50.42096,50.26414,50.33236
1/5/2007,50.37347,50.37347,50.22103,50.33459
1/6/2007,50.24433,50.24433,50.11121,50.18112
1/9/2007,49.99489,49.99489,49.80454,49.91333
1/10/2007,49.91228,50.13053,49.91228,49.97246
1/11/2007,49.88529,50.2391,49.88529,50.2391
```

Comment: Why are you trying to fetch the data in the client javascript rather than reading and parsing it in your server function? What exactly are you hoping to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to save your app file to `app.R`, exactly this name.
2. In the same folder as the app file, create a `www` folder and add your csv to that `www` folder.
3. When you reference it from js, get rid off the `www` prefix. Every path inside `www` will be relative path. e.g. you have a `www/myfile.txt`, it will be just `myfile.txt`, or if you have another subfolder, `www/sub1/file2.csv`, it will be `sub2/file2.csv`.
4. You need to use `HTML` function to wrap and escape your js code, some symbols like `>` have special meanings in HTML.
5. No need of shinyjs.

Full code:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$div(
        tags$html("Reading file"),
        tags$script(HTML("
         fetch('this_data.csv')
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(csvString => {
         // Split the csv into rows
         const rows = csvString.split('\\n');
         for (row of rows) {
         // Split the row into each of the comma separated values
           console.log(row.split(','));
         }
       });
       "))
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you did all of these, you will see:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Iz100, but nothing is displayed after "Reading file." 

Regarding versions, I have the latest shiny (1.6.0) and RStudio (1.4.1717). The rest:

platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32, 
arch: x86_64, 
os: mingw32, 
system: x86_64, mingw32, 
major: 4, 
minor: 0.4, 
year: 2021, 
month: 02, 
day: 15, 
svn rev: 80002, 
version.string: R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)

Comment: Your code is not written to display the file, but just to load the file. `console.log` only prints the results in js console, just like you use `print` in R. Nothing will be displayed on UI. If you need to display the table, you need to write the downstream code. This is not relevant to the question you have asked here.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Comment: Sincerely, I thought that the contents would be displayed.

Do I need to create a new question to know how to display the contents?

Comment: Yes, that will be ideal to ask in a different post.

Comment: Before posting a new question please read the [shiny tutorials](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial), especially [this one](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson4/) to learn how to display a reactive table.

Comment: Posted new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958652/how-to-display-table-in-shiny-from-data-read-by-javascript